# Database disappears sometimes iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, cocoa-touch

I'm having a weird behavior in my app. I'm populating my views with data from the database and sometimes the views are empty and i don't know the cause. It's like the database is closed or something so i was thinking to use some delegate methods to close and open the database to see if it fixes the problem. So the question is what of these three methods should i use and if this is a good approach?

```
applicationWillResignActive
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationWillTerminate
```

So those are to close the database, to open the database should i use a notification like:

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this database? In the bundle or on the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well be aware that `viewDidUnload` can still be called when your app is in the background and the OS need memory.
So when you clear any object in the `viewDidUnload` and not set them in the `viewDidLoad` then your views could be empty.

Comment: well, i'm not releasing anything in `viewDidUnload` i don't know the cause to this problem so i can't test it! But i'll have that in mind.